# William Faulkner's "Soldiers' Pay" first paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, sentence-meaning

The second line of the first paragraph says: "[*He suffered the same jaundice that many a more booted one than he did, from Flight Commanders through Generals to the ambrosial single-barred*](https://www.fadedpage.com/books/20181197/html.php)". I cannot wrap my mind around this after "that", i.e. "*many a more booted one than he did*". what does it mean? What is the sentence structure?

Comment: for word meanings, please consult online dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

"a more booted one than he" = "someone who was more booted than he was"

Many of the more booted ones suffered from a jaundice.  He suffered from that same jaundice.

As Arm said, "booted" and "jaundice" are in dictionaries; so tell what you found about them if you cannot understand them.

Faulkner may not be easy to read for anyone!

Comment: I suspect that "booted", in this context, means something along the lines of "high ranking".  And "jaundice" is often used metaphorically.

Comment: That's my understanding. Trivial now!

Comment: At first, the existence of "did" was confusing for me, in addition to the metaphoric meaning of "booted" . Last night I reached the above mentioned meaning. And about "did", I found out that because of the "same that" instead of "same as" we need a verb in the following. Correct me if I am wrong.